# How to add a value to list field in firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a **field** of type **array** in my **firebase** database and I want to **add** to it new **values**.

What code I want :

```dart
Firestore.instance.collection('lists').document(123).setData({
  'myList': FieldValue.add(**myValue**);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```dart
Firestore.instance.collection('lists').document(123).updateData({
  'myList': FieldValue.arrayUnion(['el1', 'el2'])
});
```

Comment: will this add to the list or reset it to these values?

Comment: @thecoder it should unite current value and new list

Comment: how about removing